# How can I make the data in a FormPanel display as text instead of in input boxes?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a **editable** FormPanel that looks like this:

[image]

I now want to display the same form but so that the data is merely **viewable** instead of editable, i.e. instead of in textboxes, the data is simply displayed as text.

I can change the defaultType from **textfield** to **panel** but then the data isn't displayed at all.

**What type of defaultType do I need so that the data value is simply displayed as text instead of in an input box?**

```
var simple_form = new Ext.FormPanel({
    labelWidth: 75,
    frame:true,
    title: 'Customer Information',
    bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
    width: 600,
    height: 600,
    autoScroll: true,
    defaults: {width: 230},
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'Item 1',
            name: 'item1',
            allowBlank:false,
            value: 'test'
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'Item 2',
            name: 'item2',
            value: 'test'
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'Item 3',
            name: 'item3',
            value: 'test'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Item 4',
            name: 'item4',
            value: 'test'
            ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Ext.form.DisplayField`. The API describes DisplayField as:

> A display-only text field which is not
>   validated and not submitted.

Set your defaultType to `defaultType: 'displayfield'`, and the `value` property to the text you want to display. Take a look at the [Composite Fields](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/composite-field.html) example. The two DisplayFields are "mins" and "hours".

Comment: that works and is ideal since I don't have to rename my "value" properties to "text", (note that it is all lowercase "displayfield", I had "defaultType: 'displayField' for while which didn't work) thanks

Comment: @Edward Tanguay: yeah I've been bitten by all lower-case before. I'm not sure why they veered away from camel-case there.

Answer (score 1):

Having had a quick scan of the Ext.Js documentation (I've never used this library before) it would appear that you need to change...

```
defaultType: 'textfield',
```

...to...

```
defaultType: 'label,
```

...and...

```
value: 'test',
```

...to...

```
text: 'test',
```

...which would result in the text fields being replaced by labels - which themselves have labels.

Not sure if it would work, but it has to be worth a try.

The only other issue remaining, would be tro prevent the users form trying to submit the form, as it isn't really a form any more, just an information panel. This statement leads me to suggest that you really ought to be using one of the other Ext.Js components, such as GridPanel.

Comment: I think a formpanel is fine in this case for layout purposes -- at least better than something like a GridPanel. A GridPanel would include a lot of unnecessary functionality like row sorting, headers, etc. that the OP would have to turn off. Then he would need to completely change the look of the GridPanel if he's going for the layout shown in his screenshot.

Comment: Ok, I'll bow to your exeperience. Didn't spot 'displayfield', but this soes make more sense that label, from a semantic point of view, and also because there is therefore no need to change 'value' to 'text'. Cool stuff.